# Convert an Object into an Object of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an Object:

```
{
"Results": {
    "circle": 0.06879016757011414,
    "quad": {
        "exp": 0.8039023876190186,
        "actual": 0.19609761238098145
    },
    "square": 0.8266428709030151
 }
}
```

I want to convert it to:

```
{
"Results": {
    "circle": {
        "circle": 0.06879016757011414
    },
    "quad": {
        "exp": 0.8039023876190186,
        "actual": 0.19609761238098145
    },
    "square": {
        "square": 0.8266428709030151
    }
  }
}
```

Have tried this code:

```
var modData = {};
data = data.Results;
for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    modData[key] = data[key];
    for (var innerKey in data[key]) {
      modData[key] = data[key];
    }
  }
}
console.log("Modified is:", modData);
```

Unfortunately, this still returns the original object, what is it that I am doing which is wrong?

A jquery solution is fine as well.

Comment: What do you want to do with your new created object in object ? What is your final intent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop trough the properties with `for .. in` and any property is not an object replace it with one. Like this:

```js
let x = {
  "Results": {
    "circle": 0.06879016757011414,
    "quad": {
      "exp": 0.8039023876190186,
      "actual": 0.19609761238098145
    },
    "square": 0.8266428709030151
  }
}
for (key in x.Results) {
  if (typeof x.Results[key] !== 'object')
    x.Results[key] = {
      [key]: x.Results[key]
    }
}

console.log(x);
```

If you want to preserve the original object do this:

```js
let data = {
  "Results": {
    "circle": 0.06879016757011414,
    "quad": {
      "exp": 0.8039023876190186,
      "actual": 0.19609761238098145
    },
    "square": 0.8266428709030151
  }
}

data = data.Results;
modData = {};

for (key in data) {
  if (typeof data[key] !== 'object')
    modData[key] = { [key]: data[key] }
  else
    modData[key] = { [key]: data[key] }
}

console.log(modData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type and if not an object then assign a new object with the same key and value.

This proposal uses [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for getting a variable as key for an object.

```js
var object = { Results: { circle: 0.06879016757011414, quad: { exp: 0.8039023876190186, actual: 0.19609761238098145 }, square: 0.8266428709030151 } };

Object
    .keys(object.Results)
    .forEach(function (k) {
        if (object.Results[k] && typeof object.Results[k] !== 'object') {
            object.Results[k] = { [k]: object.Results[k] }; 
        }
    });

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that should be stored in modData should be the object itself rather than the value. This code gives the expected value

```
var modData = {};
data = data.Results;
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var temp = Object();
        temp[key] = data[key];
        modData[key] = temp;
        for (var innerKey in data[key]) {
            var temp = Object();
            temp[key] = data[key];
            modData[key] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const input = {
        "Results": {
            "circle": 0.06879016757011414,
            "quad": {
                "exp": 0.8039023876190186,
                "actual": 0.19609761238098145
            },
            "square": 0.8266428709030151
        }
    };


    const result = {
        Results: {}
    };

    //If you want object construct specifically for "circle" & "square"
    for (let key in input.Results) {
        if (input.Results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key === 'circle') {
                result.Results.circle  = {
                    'circle': input.Results[key]
                }
            } else if (key === 'square') {
                result.Results.square = {
                    'square': input.Results[key]
                }
            } else {
                result.Results[key] = input.Results[key];
            }
        }
    }

//Generically construct object if key is not object
for (let key in input.Results) {
    if (input.Results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (key !== 'object') {
            result.Results[key] = {
                [key]: input.Results[key]
            }
        }
    }
}


    console.log(result);
```